Работа сервера MySQL
Никак не могу разобраться
Недавно решил создать проект, использующий базу данных MySQL на macOS.
Через терминал все установил, вроде все работает, удалось визуализировать, тут больших трудностей не возникло.
Однако, несмотря на это, меня не покидает вопрос, что именно я устанавливал в терминале? Что такое MySQL сервер, как явление, и как он работает? Как можно в целом визуально представить MySQL сервер на пк?
Также начал разбираться с Redis, его «сервер» подключаемый к системе является по логике как и у MySQL? Всегда ли нужно указывать именно
localhost, вместо полноценного ip при создании?

Это программа, которая создаёт сокет по адресу, который вы указали в настройках, и порту, который вы указали в настройках. Локалхост или не локалхост — зависит от того, что вы указали в настройках и от того, как устроена конфигурация вашей сети. Никто не запрещает использовать и полноценный ip, если вы пропишете соответствующие настройки и настроите вашу сеть так, чтобы при попытке обращения к нужному вам ip по нужному вам порту это обращение попадало в сокет MySQL (ну или в сокет Redis, смотря что вы там настраивать собрались)

Кстати, мне в вашем вопросе не очень нравится противопоставление «localhost» и «полноценного ip». localhost — это домен, который по умолчанию прописан в файле hosts и которму назначен ip 127.0.0.1, который вполне себе полноценный (с тем лишь нюансом, что он обычно привязан к loopback-интерфейсу вместо настоящей сетевой карты), так что вы вполне можете везде указывать 127.0.0.1 вместо localhost

Правда, тут ещё добавляется нюанс, специфичный для MySQL-клиента: если он видит, что хост указан localhost (именно домен, а не ip), он сперва попытается подключиться к unix-сокету вместо сетевого сокета. Redis и другие сетевые программы такой фигнёй не страдают
